# Android Coroutines in SyncAdapter being Interrupted

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-syncadapter

I'm having a tough time figuring out why do I observe `InterruptedException`s in the `SyncAdapter#onPerformSync` method.

#### Brief intro

My project originally contained only Java code and had a working [SyncAdapter pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter) implemented.
In the `onPerfromSync` method I did the following operations for each resource that I needed to sync:

- query local sqlite database
- send data to web server over HTTP
- save data to local sqlite database

As the project progressed I introduced Kotlin and Coroutines and decided to use them in the `SyncAdapter`. 
Most of the resources kept the existing logic, and for a few I decided to use Coroutines.
I had to bridge the `onPerformSync` method with a `CoroutineScope` so that I can launch coroutines. After doing so I started observing `InterruptedException`s occurring.

#### Code before (no exceptions)

```
class MySyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
   ...

   @Override
   public void onPerformSync(...) {
       syncResourceX();
       syncResourceY();
   }

   private void syncResourceX() {
      // query db
      // send to server
      // store locally
   }
}
```

#### Code After (with exceptions)

```
class MySyncAdapter(...): AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter(...) {
   ...

   override fun onPerformSync(...) {
      runBlocking {
              syncResourceX();
              syncResourceY();
      }
   }

   private suspend fun syncResourceX() {
      // query db
      // send to server
      // store locally
   }
}
```

After this refactoring I started receiving InterruptedExceptions where `runBlocking` is being invoked.

Initially I thought this might be due to not performing network operations on the current thread as the docs of the sync adapter state that the system monitors network traffic and might interrupt the sync process if no traffic is generated.
But `runBlocking` should cause any network requests to be executed on the current thread right?

After which I started thinking that this process has existed in the Java code as well. It's just that there is nothing to report the interruption of the sync process. It is up until I started using coroutines and runBlocking that this problem has revealed it self. Or so I think now.

#### Question:

Any thoughts or explanations why I previously did not observe InterruptedException with the Java code and do observe  InterruptedException with the Kotlin code is more than welcome.

**Notes**

- I haven't overriden onSyncCanceled
- The sync process usually takes less then 20 seconds to complete

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve this somehow?

Comment: Not yet, I think you need to override onSyncCanceled and have your coroutine code check if cancel was called. I think that onSyncCanceled is called before the actual thread gets interrupted. So you need to honor this interruption.

However I am currently migrating to WorkManager.

Comment: Thanks! I resorted to using `runBlocking {}` which works out fine. Android will create a new thread for the sync operation anyway, so it's good. Just need to make sure any of your internal `suspend` functions don't run on other threads.